# Error when installing packages with conda

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to install some pipelines using `conda` but I'm getting the following error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 764, in read_chunked
        self._update_chunk_length()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 694, in _update_chunk_length
        line = self._fp.fp.readline()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 760, in generate
        for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
        for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 793, in read_chunked
        self._original_response.close()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
        raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1080, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 41, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 259, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
        subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
        self.load()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 210, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 375, in _load
        raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 701, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 687, in send
        r.content
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 838, in content
        self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
        raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

`$ /home/tamer/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n snakePipes -c mpi-ie -c conda-forge -c bioconda snakePipes`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/tamer/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/tamer/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 INFOPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
                  MANPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
                     PATH=/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin:/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.l
                          inuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/tamer/.local/bin:/h
                          ome/tamer/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:
                          /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/tamer/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/tamer/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/tamer/.condarc
          conda version : 4.11.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.7
         python version : 3.9.10.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/tamer/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/tamer/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/mpi-ie/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/mpi-ie/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/tamer/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/tamer/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/tamer/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/tamer/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.10 Linux/5.4.0-96-generic ubuntu/20.04.3 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

Even when I am updating `conda`:

```
$ conda update --all --yes

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 764, in read_chunked
        self._update_chunk_length()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 694, in _update_chunk_length
        line = self._fp.fp.readline()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 760, in generate
        for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
        for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 793, in read_chunked
        self._original_response.close()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
        raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1080, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 259, in install
        unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 114, in solve_for_transaction
        unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(update_modifier, deps_modifier,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 157, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(update_modifier, deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 425, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1020, in _prepare
        reduced_index = get_reduced_index(self.prefix, self.channels,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 288, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = SubdirData.query_all(spec, channels=channels, subdirs=subdirs,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 140, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 132, in <lambda>
        subdir_query = lambda url: tuple(SubdirData(Channel(url), repodata_fn=repodata_fn).query(
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 145, in query
        self.load()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 210, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 375, in _load
        raw_repodata_str = fetch_repodata_remote_request(
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 701, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        resp = session.get(join_url(url, filename), headers=headers, proxies=session.proxies,
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 687, in send
        r.content
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 838, in content
        self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
      File "/home/tamer/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 763, in generate
        raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

`$ /home/tamer/anaconda3/bin/conda update --all --yes`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin/conda
             CONDA_PREFIX=/home/tamer/anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/tamer/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 INFOPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:
                  MANPATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man:
                     PATH=/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin:/home/tamer/anaconda3/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.l
                          inuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/tamer/.local/bin:/h
                          ome/tamer/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:
                          /usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : /home/tamer/anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/tamer/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/tamer/.condarc
          conda version : 4.11.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.7
         python version : 3.9.10.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=5.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/tamer/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/tamer/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/tamer/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/tamer/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/tamer/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/tamer/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.11.0 requests/2.27.1 CPython/3.9.10 Linux/5.4.0-96-generic ubuntu/20.04.3 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1001:1001
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

I am trying to use `conda` to install snakePipes. I tried all the possible solutions on StackOverflow and other platforms but non is working. I am using Ubuntu  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-96-generic x86_64.

Comment: The error means the remote server disconnected you. We can't see where you are trying to connect so it's really not possible to tell you anything more than what's already in the error message.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. what I am trying to is: `$conda create -n snakePipes -c mpi-ie -c conda-forge -c bioconda snakePipes`